# constructing sth like timespan

Tags: c++, qt

i want draw a `rectangle` for showing `time` and users can select time intervals in it, something like below image, but i don't know how to do this in Qt, is there any `widget` that i can use it? or if i should implement myself how can i do this? i googled it and i found a `QTimeSpan` but it is not added to Qt yet. or is it possible to change `QSlider` to have two side slide for selecting time?
thank you in advance[image]

Comment: You have to build it yourself, even QTimeSpan seems to be slightly different. I would not go for implementing a widget though, but rather take the direction towards Qt Quick 2.